# How to check two vectors of different types for equality

Tags: c++, vector, operator-overloading, equality

I have two vectors, `a`, `b`, of structs `abc` and `abc2` respectively:

```
struct abc {
    const int &data;
    abc(const int& cdata) : data(cdata) {}
};

struct abc2 {
    const int& data;
    abc2(const int& cdata) : data(cdata) {}

    bool operator== (const abc& c1) const {
        return (c1.data == data);
    }
};

int main() {

    std::vector<abc> a{abc(2), abc(2)};
    std::vector<abc2> b{abc2(2), abc2(2)};

}
```

And I want to see if `a` and `b` are equal.

However when I attempt the following:

```
assert(a == b);
```

I get a compile time error of

> Error  C2678   binary '==': no operator found which takes a left-hand operand of type 'std::vector<abc,std::allocator<_Ty>>' (or there is no acceptable conversion)
> with
> [
> _Ty=abc
> ]

How can I implement a custom equality check for these two vectors of different types? I do not ever need to do `abc` == `abc2` so a overload equals operator is not required for the `abc` struct.

Comment: The dupe seems to answer the question in your title. Is that what you're looking for, or are you trying to actually get `==` to work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a standard algorithm for comparing equality: `std::equal`. In this case

```
assert(std::equal(b.begin(), b.end(), a.begin(), a.end()));
```

Comment: You can use an overload of `std::equal` that takes four iterators instead of checking sizes explicitly.

Comment: @Evg Oh nice, they added those in C++14.